# What does w/ mean in Factor w/ levels in R?

Tags: r

I learned about how to make num in to factor.

So when I run `k = factor(c(1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 3))` on the source panel I get `Factor w/ 4 levels "1", "2", "3", "4": 1 2 2 3 4 3` on the *Environment* panel.

I understand everything in this line except `w/`. And I just cannot find it on internet.

Comment: I do not know the exact meaning of it but I read it as "Factor with 4 levels".

Comment: `w/` is an abbreviation for "with" (in English, not specific to R). `w/o` is an abbreviation for "without". See https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/115367/are-w-o-w-b-c-common-abbreviations-in-the-us

Comment: Omg, it was an English abbreviation! no wonders it didn't show up when I searched with R. Thanks!

Comment: @Marius post as answer please.

Comment: @Marius yes please do post as answer. This would not be obvious to non-English speakers. I wondered the same myself when I first used R